# Devstack installation error - Initializing Designate - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_defaults'

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, attributeerror, devstack

recently I've been re-installing Devstack successfully couple of times.
Today I got following error:

```
==> default: 2016-11-10 13:26:02.723 | Initializing Designate
==> default: Traceback (most recent call last):
==> default:   File "/usr/local/bin/designate-manage", line 10, in <module>
==> default:     
==> default: sys.exit(main())
==> default:   File "/opt/stack/designate/designate/cmd/manage.py", line 110, in main
==> default:     utils.read_config('designate', sys.argv)
==> default:   File "/opt/stack/designate/designate/utils.py", line 109, in read_config
==> default:     config.set_defaults()
==> default:   File "/opt/stack/designate/designate/common/config.py", line 21, in set_defaults
==> default:     cors.set_defaults(
==> default: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_defaults'
==> default: Error on exit
```

The installation was done on in 2 environments:

1. Vagrant + VirtualBox - "ubuntu/trusty64" image + branch *stable/mitaka*
2. VMWare Fusion with Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS server image + branch *stable/mitaka*

In each case the same error occurs.

Both todays and every previous (successful) installations have been done with the Designate plugin enabled in local.conf:

```
# Enable designate
enable_plugin designate https://git.openstack.org/openstack/designate   

# Designate Devstack Config
# =========================
# Enable core Designate services
enable_service designate,designate-central,designate-api,designate-pool-manager,designate-zone-manager,designate-mdns
```

Looks like some version mismatch between the *designate* and *oslo.middleware* Python modules, which came out in recent days (or hours).

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that stumbles here:

I was getting an error upgrading to `ocata` because the `keystone-wsgi-public` script was trying to call `cors.set_defaults` (and throwing the same error). This cors depdency was provided as part of the `python2-oslo-middleware` RPM and needed to be `yum upgrade`d by hand for me (soft dependency).

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the error because of the following commit:
https://github.com/openstack/designate/commit/04374fcb53bc5c4d5cfb058907d5b351ed546a38

It was my bad though, because I should declare the *stable/mitaka* branch for the plugin (more generally - the same branch as the one for Devstack clone), so it should go like follows:

```
# Enable designate
enable_plugin designate https://git.openstack.org/openstack/designate stable/mitaka
```

The above solves my problem.